# What are your best Sequel tips?

Tags: ruby, sequel

[Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) is an excellent Ruby ORM and a worthy alternative to ActiveRecord.  It's very well documented and powerful.  But it's still got some tricky bits.  What tips have you found to make working with Sequel easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're coming from Rails, note that connection option keys and values used in Sequel are spelled differently than those in `database.yml`:

```
db_config {
    :adapter => 'postgres',        # NOT 'postgresql'
    :default_schema  => 'public',  # NOT :schema_search_path
    :user => 'myusername',         # NOT :username
    :password => 'mypassword',
    :host => 'myhost',
    :database => 'mydb',
    :max_connections => 5          # NOT :pool'
}
DB = Sequel.connect db_config
```